# Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Exit code is 143

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm trying to run a very small mr job using a 2MB [file](https://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.data), I get the error below. By checking the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533501/hadoop-mapper-is-failing-because-of-container-killed-by-the-applicationmaster/34164109), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972908/container-killed-by-the-applicationmaster-exit-code-is-143), and [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/96183/help-troubleshoot-container-killed-by-the-applicat.html) which are addressing the same problem, it looks like it's a memory problem. However, it's unclear how it should be fixed. There is a `yarn-site.xml` that was mentioned in one of the answers which needs to be modified but I can't locate it, so what should I do to be able to run the job successfully?

```
[root@sandbox-hdp maria_dev]# python3.9 rating_count.py -r hadoop --hadoop-streaming-jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar u.data 
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for hadoop runner
Looking for hadoop binary in $PATH...
Found hadoop binary: /usr/bin/hadoop
Using Hadoop version 2.7.3.2.6.5.0
Creating temp directory /tmp/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567
uploading working dir files to hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567/files/wd...
Copying other local files to hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567/files/
Running step 1 of 1...
  packageJobJar: [] [/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292.jar] /tmp/streamjob5489481114017321662.jar tmpDir=null
  Connecting to ResourceManager at sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/172.18.0.2:8032
  Connecting to Application History server at sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/172.18.0.2:10200
  Connecting to ResourceManager at sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/172.18.0.2:8032
  Connecting to Application History server at sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/172.18.0.2:10200
  Total input paths to process : 1
  number of splits:2
  Submitting tokens for job: job_1633446390550_0011
  Submitted application application_1633446390550_0011
  The url to track the job: http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1633446390550_0011/
  Running job: job_1633446390550_0011
  Job job_1633446390550_0011 running in uber mode : false
   map 0% reduce 0%
   map 50% reduce 0%
  Task Id : attempt_1633446390550_0011_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 

  Task Id : attempt_1633446390550_0011_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 

   map 0% reduce 0%
  Task Id : attempt_1633446390550_0011_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

  Task Id : attempt_1633446390550_0011_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

  Task Id : attempt_1633446390550_0011_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

  Task Id : attempt_1633446390550_0011_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 

   map 100% reduce 100%
  Job job_1633446390550_0011 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1633446390550_0011_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

  Job not successful!
  Streaming Command Failed!
Counters: 17
    Job Counters 
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Failed map tasks=7
        Killed map tasks=1
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=8
        Other local map tasks=6
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=27223000
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=108892
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=108892
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=108892
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
Scanning logs for probable cause of failure...
Looking for history log in /var/log/hadoop-yarn...
Looking for history log in /var/log/hadoop...

Probable cause of failure:

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 


Step 1 of 1 failed: Command '['/usr/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567/files/wd/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip,hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567/files/wd/rating_count.py#rating_count.py,hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567/files/wd/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567/files/u.data', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/maria_dev/tmp/mrjob/rating_count.maria_dev.20211005.201624.647567/output', '-mapper', '/bin/sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 rating_count.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-reducer', '/bin/sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 rating_count.py --step-num=0 --reducer']' returned non-zero exit status 256.
[root@sandbox-hdp maria_dev]#
```

Comment: Find the real logs from `The url to track the job ` link

Comment: Also, 2MB file nowhere near large enough for using Hadoop. You could just as easily install pyspark locally outside of any VM and process that file (plus, the sandboxes are no longer supported/maintained, like I said before)

Comment: I know, the thing is I'm following some [course](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-ultimate-hands-on-hadoop-tame-your-big-data/) that uses the sandbox to explain the basics of hadoop and other tools including ambari, spark, storm, kafka, ... The guy in the course said mapreduce is not that attractive nowadays and there are many alternatives that replaced it but he's showing an example for demonstration purposes. If there is a free alternative that has the same stack in one place which is being maintained, that I can use to follow along the course, let me know and I'd definitely go for it

Comment: Everything that can be done with Mapreduce can be done directly in IntelliJ directly. You dont need HDFS or YARN. Here's an example repo of mine https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox  `mrjob` python code can also be deployed on a "local running" that doesn't require a Hadoop environment, similar to PySpark or Apache Pig

Comment: In any case, code 143 is likely a memory problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52403247/2308683

Comment: Turns out not a memory problem, I'm using `python3.9` which I installed without having it symlinked as `python3` which in turn, is invoked somewhere and not found. I fixed the problem by creating the missing symlink and it's working fine.

Comment: From what I recall, the sandbox doesn't come with Python3.9, and its probably not a requirement for the course you're following

Comment: Yeah, it's not a requirement. In fact the course uses `python2` for this example and I decided not to. The problem is that errors are subtle this way, if at any given point, python code fails, you will never know what went wrong, and you only get a java error which is misleading.

Comment: That's not completely true. The YARN container logs themselves have the real error. The logs you've shown are from the Mapreduce framework, not the actual running processes within

Comment: Where can I find these logs? I tried looking in the yarn section in the ui, but couldn't tell where to look

Comment: _`...subprocess failed with code 127...`_ -- code 127 usually indicates app-level issue, which as you found out in your case was container initialization due to missing python.

Comment: Each YARN process is an "application". You would go to the `application/ID` URL (given by the MR job), then from there multiple "containers" are started, each with their own logs link. From those links, you have `stdout`, `stderr`, and `syslog`... You can also use `yarn logs` CLI commands