# Hadoop - Exception when trying to cleanup container. ExitCode = 143

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

When I use hadoop - Pseudo-Distributed Operation.

I try a demo - wordcount, and then it throw This Exception [WARN] .

```
 Exception when trying to cleanup container. xxxxxxxxxx  ExitCode = 143
```

And it stuck at

```
map 100%， reduce 0%.
```

What wrong with it ?

My Hadoop Singleton have used  2.6/8 GB Memory, 8/8 vCores.

Comment: I suspect you'll find the real error in the YARN UI logs for the map task

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container killed by the ApplicationMaster Exit code is 143](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972908/container-killed-by-the-applicationmaster-exit-code-is-143)

Comment: I have fix this error. Not the YARN UI logs.

Comment: The Bug is Ubuntu-OS 21.x can't run it.
And I move it to the CentOS-7 and it can run.
And it's config file is the same as the URL：
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html
wtf....